# ScrollToTop not workng only in IE Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the scroll to top fade in fade out functionality. This works fine with Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Opera. But doesn't work on Safari and IE Edge. I don't know why this isn't happening only in these 2 browsers. This is what I have tried so far.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 475) {
        $('#btn-back-ttop').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $('#btn-back-ttop').fadeOut(300);
    }
});

$("#btn-back-ttop").click(function(){
    $("html").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
});
```

PS: I have also tried a suggested solution to set the height of body and html to auto and setting min-height to 100% too. That doesn't seem to help much. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 'html' with 'html,body'

i.e.

```
$("#btn-back-ttop").click(function(){
    $("html").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
});
```

should be

```
$("#btn-back-ttop").click(function(){
    $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :)

HTML CODE

```
<div class="back-to-top">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" rel="nofollow"><span class="fa fa-arrow-up"></span></a>
    </div>
```

JS CODE

```
// BACK TO TOP
$('.back-to-top').hide(); // HIDE ON FIRST LOAD
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
    }
});
$('.back-to-top a').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
```